# PHP - show recaptcha in ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

I have added recaptcha to my php login form. The form counts the number of failed attempts and displays the recaptcha if the number of allowed attempt is exceeded. This works great with a plain PHP form. If however the form is submitted with ajax (jquery), there is no page refresh so the captcha does not become visible.

The recaptcha code in my login form looks like this:

```
<!-- recaptcha -->
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['PL_LOGIN_COUNT'])) $_SESSION['PL_LOGIN_COUNT'] = 0;
    if(PL_LOGIN_CAPTCHA_ON || !PL_LOGIN_CAPTCHA_ON && $_SESSION['PL_LOGIN_COUNT'] > PL_MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPT) {
        echo '<label for="recaptcha_response_field">';
        echo $plLang->get('LNG_26');
        echo '</label>';
        require_once(PL_ABSPATH.'pl-lib/lib-recaptcha.php');
        $publickey = PL_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY;
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    }?>
```

Any suggestions would be great.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about the AJAX will display an captcha JSON code, and a javascript function which will make a action based on the AJAX result?